# ssh git - logged in as another user

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I run the following command on my machine (not locally):

```
ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org
```

and get as output

```
logged in as maxifl
```

This user is old and I use another user.

- How do I change the user?

Moreover, I get an error while I run "git pull"

```
conq: repository access denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

- What do you think caused to this issue? How can I fix it on my remote machine?

Comment: This depends on the SSH key that you are using. Do you have multiple SSH keys on your machine, or only one?

Comment: Not multiple *users*. Multiple *SSH keys*. Do you remember adding any SSH keys to your user's BitBucket profile? Those identify you as that user. The key that you are using is associated with your old user. Either remove it from the old user account and add it to your new one, or generate a new key and use it with your new account.

Comment: Sorry I meant to SSH keys. I already have the new SSH key within my bitbucket account and within autorized_keys. Is there anything else I need do?

Comment: It probably wouldn't need to go into `authorized_keys` on your development machine. That's for connecting to your development machine from elsewhere, not for outgoing connections. You may have an agent running that is still holding your old SSH key. Try `ssh-add -l` from the command line and see if your old key shows up. You may also have a graphical tool that does this. Have you rebooted since generating the new key? That might be enough to cause the old one to be forgotten.

Comment: I eventually solved it by storing the server key into my bitbucket account - SSH keys.